# Simple add function with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a very simple function in jQuery, in which I add the input values ​​of two input-fields (type text) and output the result.

I get either NaN or no result. Have tried it already with parseInt(), but also had no success.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
function output() {
        var stellplaetze = $('.stellplaetze').val();
        var miete = $('.miete').val();
        var result = stellplaetze * miete * 30;
        $('.result').html(
          '<strong class="text-uppercase">Ertrag pro Monat: </strong><br> ' +
            result +
            ' EUR'
        );
      }
      
$(function() {
    // Trigger the function
    $('button').on('click', function() {
      output();
      $('#ertragsrechner .result').css('opacity', 1);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formbody">
        <input type="hidden" name="FORM_SUBMIT" value="auto_form_5">
        <input type="hidden" name="REQUEST_TOKEN" value="pC9vYIP8oBzVONQiwg-ixrLwDhEdK0LA8-5n-6kQJPw">
        <div class="widget widget-text stellplaetze">
            <input type="text" name="stellplaetze" id="ctrl_12"
                class="text stellplaetze form-control flex-fill mr-0 mr-sm-2 mb-3" value=""
                placeholder="Anzahl der Stellplätze">
        </div>
        <div class="widget widget-text miete">
            <input type="text" name="miete" id="ctrl_13" class="text miete form-control flex-fill mr-0 mr-sm-2 mb-3"
                value="" placeholder="Miete pro Tag">
        </div>
        <div class="widget widget-submit add">
            <button type="submit" id="ctrl_15" class="submit add btn btn-primary">Ertrag berechnen</button>
        </div>
        <div class="widget widget-explanation explanation result">
            <p>Ertrag Pro Monat</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you also post the relevant html? (What is `.stellplaetze` and `.miete`)

Comment: have you tried to debug? are you sure `stellplaetze` and `miete` variables are all numbers?

Comment: `$(".class").val()` returns strings

Comment: @jro Not true: `"12"*"13"` will yield 156 even with spaces around the numbers.

Comment: @ZorgoZ Wow I did not know that, thanks

Comment: You're targeting these input fields by classes, are you sure it's getting the correct instances? Could you target your fields with an ID and see if you get the same results?

Comment: @jro only `+` has dual meaning between strings and numbers - other mathematical operations implicitly convert operands to numbers. It's still a good idea to keep the types correct, though, and not rely on implicit casting during the expression. The simplest example is that six months from now, you want to modify the equation `a * b` where both are strings, so you change it to `(a + 2) * b` and now it's incorrect because of the string concatenation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the issue is with the selector be more specific since there are multiple elements with the same class name. In your case, you can add `input` along with class selector.

By default jQuery [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method just retrieves the value of the first element in the collection, in your case, it's the `div` element.

*From jQuery docs:*

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements

```js
function output() {
  var stellplaetze = $('input.stellplaetze').val();stellplaetze
  // here --------------^^^^^^---------
  var miete = $('input.miete').val();
  // here -------^^^^^^---------
  var result = stellplaetze * miete * 30;
  $('.result').html(
    '<strong class="text-uppercase">Ertrag pro Monat: </strong><br> ' +
    result +
    ' EUR'
  );
}

// Trigger the function
$('#ertragsrechner button').on('click', function() {
  output();
  $('#ertragsrechner .result').css('opacity', 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ertragsrechner">
  <div class="formbody">
    <input type="hidden" name="FORM_SUBMIT" value="auto_form_5">
    <input type="hidden" name="REQUEST_TOKEN" value="pC9vYIP8oBzVONQiwg-ixrLwDhEdK0LA8-5n-6kQJPw">
    <div class="widget widget-text stellplaetze">
      <input type="text" name="stellplaetze" id="ctrl_12" class="text stellplaetze form-control flex-fill mr-0 mr-sm-2 mb-3" value="" placeholder="Anzahl der Stellplätze">
    </div>
    <div class="widget widget-text miete">
      <input type="text" name="miete" id="ctrl_13" class="text miete form-control flex-fill mr-0 mr-sm-2 mb-3" value="" placeholder="Miete pro Tag">
    </div>
    <div class="widget widget-submit add">
      <button type="submit" id="ctrl_15" class="submit add btn btn-primary">Ertrag berechnen</button>
    </div>
    <div class="widget widget-explanation explanation result">
      <p>Ertrag Pro Monat</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: t works now. But I think I did not use the classes more than once. Really strange..

Many Thanks!

Comment: @Codehan25 you have the same class on the input and the div containing the input.

Comment: @Codehan25 : just search `stellplaetze` in your code ;)

Comment: @Codehan25 :  glad to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all the variables are retrieved from an input box, while multiplying change the variables to numbers using `Number()`

```
var result = Number(stellplaetze) * Number(miete) * 30;
```

There are multiple elements with same class in the html. To Select the input with the class miete and stellplaetze use input .classname as the jquery selector

```js
function output() {
        var stellplaetze = $('input.stellplaetze').val();
        var miete = $('input.miete').val();
        var result = Number(stellplaetze) * Number(miete) * 30;
        $('.result').html(
          '<strong class="text-uppercase">Ertrag pro Monat: </strong><br> ' +
            result +
            ' EUR'
        );
      }
      
$(function() {
    // Trigger the function
    $('button').on('click', function() {
      output();
      $('#ertragsrechner .result').css('opacity', 1);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formbody">
        <input type="hidden" name="FORM_SUBMIT" value="auto_form_5">
        <input type="hidden" name="REQUEST_TOKEN" value="pC9vYIP8oBzVONQiwg-ixrLwDhEdK0LA8-5n-6kQJPw">
        <div class="widget widget-text stellplaetze">
            <input type="text" name="stellplaetze" id="ctrl_12"
                class="text stellplaetze form-control flex-fill mr-0 mr-sm-2 mb-3" value=""
                placeholder="Anzahl der Stellplätze">
        </div>
        <div class="widget widget-text miete">
            <input type="text" name="miete" id="ctrl_13" class="text miete form-control flex-fill mr-0 mr-sm-2 mb-3"
                value="" placeholder="Miete pro Tag">
        </div>
        <div class="widget widget-submit add">
            <button type="submit" id="ctrl_15" class="submit add btn btn-primary">Ertrag berechnen</button>
        </div>
        <div class="widget widget-explanation explanation result">
            <p>Ertrag Pro Monat</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the same class name on many elements, while the jQuery documentation on the `val()` method says

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.

So you have either to iterate over the elements array or change the class name of the input element

Comment: You don't need to change the class - you just need a more precise selector. Remember that selectors aren't just "by ID" or "by class" - [there is a lot more that you can do with them](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: @VLAZ of course not, but in my experience I’d rather rename a class to also have a more specific clue at what that class does when going through the code after months.

Comment: And I'd rather NOT rename classes without knowing what CSS rules are behind them. Maybe I rename this and the input box is now bright red and moved to the right-hand side. A better CSS selector in your code isn't bad, it's even more helpful in a lot of cases - if I see `$("input.stellplaetze")` I immediately know what the element is. Making a `stellplaetzeInput` class is redundant. It's also annoying, since you can't reuse its styling for, say, a div. Unless you start exploding your CSS spreadsheet rules with `.stellplaetzeInput, .stellplaetzeDiv, .stellplaetzeP` etc.